# WPF listView Getting Checked Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list view, of which the first column is checkboxes to enable/disable the item which represents said row. The problem is, when I change the checkbox, it does not select the row. Thus, when inside my checkBox checked/unchecked event I do `listView.SelectedItem`, it is null and crashes. Is there any way to fix this behavior so the listView check will select the item? Or, if there is an equivalent `CheckedItems` property in WPF like there is in WinForms?

XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="StatusHeader" Header="Status" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Margin="5, 0" IsChecked="{Binding loaded}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="NameHeader" Header="Name" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```cs
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    module v = (module)listView1.SelectedItem; // crash
    _client.AddClientModule(v.path);
}

private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    module v = (module)listView1.SelectedItem; // crash
    _client.RemoveClientModule(v.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataContext` to access the *ViewModel* and manually select it (if it is desired).

```cs
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    var v = (module)cb.DataContext;

    _client.AddClientModule(v.path);

    // Select manually
    listView1.SelectedItem = v;
}

private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    var v = (module)cb.DataContext;

    _client.RemoveClientModule(v.path);

    // Select manually
    listView1.SelectedItem = v;
}
```